# Mediation Software Patterns

Tags: java, design-patterns

I want to write a Mediation Software in Java and I want to know which design patterns I should use to  do this.
NB : A Mediation Software is used in the domain to telecommunication to collect and distribute file to differents outputs via FTP.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide more insight into your requirements.  What is the granularity, one file or many; Does the file go to one end-point, some or all?  What is the timelyness expectation?  Are they all the same priority.  What if the end-point is unreachable, should the file be queued or replaced by the latests.

Comment: Hi, the software should be able to collect files by a time interval, to manage different collect points and different distribution points (one input for many output), to keep a file in system until it is completely send to the destination, to resend a file if needed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't start by looking for design patterns. Start by making the requirements very clear and then considering the objects and responsibilities that emerge from satisfying the requirements. As you improve your object design you start to find a need to control dependencies and increase flexibility, and at that point you being to see design patterns.

For example: suppose you receive several different data formats and need to transform them in the mediation. Then you might have some transformer classes able to do say JSON->XML, CSV->XML, SpecialData->XML. You begin to see commonality between those transformer classes and how instances are created. Then patterns such as Facade or AbstractFactory might emerge.